# Apache Url Rewrite Conflict

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm running on a apache server and i have problem with url rewrite conflicts
tech Stack im using is LAMP Stack using Cyberpanel

The Folder Structure is

```
ai-tools/
         index.php
banks/
         index.php
         banks.php
categeories/
         index.php
deals/
         index.php
events/
         index.php
         events.php
exclusive-sales/
         index.php
popular-offers/
         index.php
top-stores/
         index.php
stores/
         index.php
index.php
store.php
```

i want to rewrite the urls like :

```
domain.com/ae/store.php?name=xyz to  domain.com/ae/xyz/
doman.com/ae/categeory/index.php?name=xyz to domain.com/ae/categeory/xyz/ 
domain.com/ae/banks/banks.php?name=abcd-offers to   domain.com/ae/banks/abcd-offers/ 
domain.com/ae/banks/index.php  to  domain.com/ae/banks/ 
domain.com/ae/deals/index.php  to  domain.com/ae/deals/
domain.com/ae/popular-offers/index.php to domain.com/ae/popular-offers/
domain.com/ae/ai-tools/index.php to domain.com/ae/ai-tools/
domain.com/ae/events/events.php?name=abcd to   domain.com/ae/events/abcd/ 
domain.com/ae/events/index.php  to  domain.com/ae/events/ 
domain.com/ae/stores/index.php to domain.com/ae/stores/
domain.com/ae/top-stores/index.php?name=xyx to domain.com/ae/top-stores/xyz/
```

htaccess i have is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]`

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}  !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
<Directory /uploads>
    Allow from all
   Options +Indexes
   Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory "/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

AddType image/jpeg .jpg .jpeg
AddType image/png  .png
AddType image/gif  .gif

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^ae/categeories/index\.php /ae/categeories/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^ae/categeories/ /ae/categeories/index.php[QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^ae/banks/index\.php /ae/banks/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^ae/banks/ /ae/banks/index.php[QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^ae/stores/index\.php /ae/stores/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^ae/stores/ /ae/stores/index.php[QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^ae/events/index\.php /ae/events/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^ae/events/ /ae/events/index.php[QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^ae/delas/index\.php /ae/deals/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^ae/deals/ /ae/deals/index.php[QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^ae/popular-offers/index\.php /ae/popular-offers/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^ae/popular-offers/ /ae/popular-offers/index.php[QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^ae/deals/index\.php /ae/deals/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^ae/deals/ /ae/deals/index.php[QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^ae/ai-tools/index\.php /ae/ai-tools/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^ae/ai-tools/ /ae/ai-tools/index.php[QSA,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^ae/categeories/index\.php$ /ae/categeories/%1/? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^ae/categeories/([^/]+)/?$ /ae/categeories/index.php?cat=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^ae/top-store/index\.php$ /ae/top-store/%1/? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^ae/top-stores/([^/]+)/?$ /ae/top-stores/index.php?cat=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^ae/banks/banks\.php$ /ae/banks/%1/? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^ae/banks/([^/]+)/?$ /ae/banks/banks.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^ae/events/events\.php$ /ae/events/%1/? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^ae/events/([^/]+)/?$ /ae/events/events.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^ae/store\.php$ /ae/%1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^ae/([^/]+)/?$ /ae/store.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]


RewriteRule ^about\.php$ /about [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^privacy-policy\.php$ /privacy-policy [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^terms-of-service\.php$ /terms-of-service [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^help\.php$ /help [R=301,L]

<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$">
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.php
```

i have attached the folder structure url structure and the htaccess im using
the problem with the current htaccess i cannot access most of the urls